# Lamar alternative to StructureMap Forward()

Tags: structuremap, lamar

In StructureMap you could declare a `Forward<,>` statement, that would allow for registering a single concrete instance to be resolved by multiple interfaces from the [StructureMap documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/forwarding-requests-for-a-type-to-another-type/):

```cs
var container = new Container(_ =>
{
    // Let's make StatefulCache a SingletonThing in the container
    _.ForConcreteType<StatefulCache>().Configure.Singleton();

    _.Forward<StatefulCache, IReader>();
    _.Forward<StatefulCache, IWriter>();
});

container.GetInstance<IReader>().ShouldBeOfType<StatefulCache>();
container.GetInstance<IWriter>().ShouldBeOfType<StatefulCache>();
```

I am looking at potentially migrating to Lamar, the replacement for StructureMap but I am not seeing anything matching this in the registration options.

Is this possible in Lamar?

Answer (score 5):

According to [StructureMap documentation](https://structuremap.github.io/the-container/forwarding-requests-for-a-type-to-another-type/) *the syntax has consistently been confusing to users* and the suggested replacement is:

```cs
_.For<IReader>().Use(c => c.GetInstance<StatefulCache>());
```

So I would suggest using this lambda approach.